# Given two circles externaly tangent to each other and the common tangent line. Draw a third tangent circle.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles, geometric-construction, geometric-transformation

We are given $\Gamma_A$ centered at $A$ and $\Gamma_B$ centered at $B$ tangent to each other externally at $C$. Line $DE$ is one common tangent to both not through $C$.

[image]

Is there a nice way to draw the red circle externally tangent to both and to line $DE$ without using the complete apollonius solution for the $CCL$? Are there any nice symetries in this problem?

I only saw the homotheties which would mean a few tangency points would be colinear and of course Monge-D'Alembert theorem implies one more colinearity between the tangency points and the exterior homothetic center

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use inversion with center at $O$ (touching point of given circle) and arbitrary radius (I've choose $r$ = distance of $O$ to given line for ease). So we are looking at inversion with respect to red circle.

Mark all given objects with dots.

Now both circles goes to parallel and line goes to a circle touching both lines. Now the image of a circle we are searching (blue) is a circle touching these twi parallels and circle between them and on a picture is green circle (and it is easy to draw it). Now map this green and you get blue circle, the one we are searching.

[image]

Comment: this is nice one!

Comment: this is a nice one still I'm having it bad drawing the green circle. I thought the line joining it with the center of the inversion one would be parallel to the others.

Comment: Yes, draw that line and  where it cuts black circle is touching point of green with black. Radius of green is same as black.

Comment: lol i didn't draw the black one, sorry

Answer (score 2):

If the radius of the circle $A$ is $a$ and of $B$ is $b$, $DE = 2\sqrt{ab}$.

Say, the center of red circle is $O$, the radius $= r$, and parallel line to $DE$ through $O$ meets $AE$ at $A'$ and $BD$ at $B'$.

$DE = OA' + OB'$
or, $2\sqrt{ab} = 2\sqrt{ar} + 2\sqrt{br}$
or, $r = \frac{ab}{a+b+2\sqrt{ab}}$

Now that we know the value of $r$, draw A'B' parallel line to $DE$ at a distance $r$.

Use a compass to draw an arc from center $A$ with radius $a+r$. Wherever it cuts the line $A'B'$ is point $O$, the center of the red circle. Now you can draw the circle of radius $r$ from the center.

Comment: Yes, but you don't know what $a$ and $b$ are. And how do you construct $r$ from that formula?

Comment: It says two given circles so I assume you know their radius.

Comment: Unforunately you can't. If I draw a circle with radius $r$, you don't know what it is unless I told you.

Comment: If you do not know $a$ and $b$ then I agree but if you know, this works.

Comment: Yes, I agree, but still, how you draw $r$ exactly if say $a=\pi$ and $b=e$.

Comment: Anway, nice work +1

Comment: If we know a and b, we can find $r$. That is what I found in my solution.

Comment: Btw I see your point about $\pi$, $e$ :)   knowing will be one thing and drawing will be another as I do not know it exactly!

Answer (score 0):

I did it. It uses a generalization of a result involving a chain of tangent circles that look like this:

[Given the following tangent circles chain to draw the next circle of the chain](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3776966/given-the-following-tangent-circles-chain-to-draw-the-next-circle-of-the-chain)

To a degenerate case. Anyway here it is:

Let the two given circles $\Gamma _A$ and $\Gamma _B$ touch the line $\ell$ at points $A \in \Gamma _A$ and $B \in \Gamma _B$. Take $C$ to be the antipode of $A$ on $\Gamma _A$ and $D$ the antipode of $B$ on $\Gamma _B$.

Draw the tangent line from $D$ to $\Gamma _A$ (there are two tangent lines, right? Take the one such that the contact point $T$ is in the small region between $\Gamma _A$ and $\Gamma _B$).

Take $G = CT \cap \ell$. To end it just draw the perpendicular bissector of $GT$ and let it meet with a line perpendicular to $\ell$ through $G$ to get the center $O$ of the third circle and draw it centered at $O$ passing through $G$.